# Question about Central Limit Theorem with an example

Tags: probability, distributions, central-limit-theorem

“If height in centimeters in some given population is distributed with mean 175 and standard deviation 10, the central limit theorem implies that the probability of finding a person taller than 177 centimeters in any random sample of size 100 is approximately 2.5%.”

I don't think this statement is true because central limit theorem speaks about the SAMPLE MEAN probability and not the probability of an individual person.

Is that the correct way to think about it?

Comment: The standard deviation and your probability do not fit, so something at least is wrong there.

Comment: @Forgotten Did you remember to compute the standard error?

Comment: @Whuber I buy that the standard error here is 1 for the sample, but I am reading it as "height $\sim N(175, 10^2)$, then if I draw 100 samples from this distribution, the probability that at least 1 person is taller than 177 is 2.5%," which is obviously false. I can only imagine that is incorrect on my part - I am in essence probably just repeating the mistake of the asker. I do follow that they imply that the probability of observing a sample mean larger than 177 is less than 2.5%, but that isn't what they've written.

Comment: @Forgotten Your logic is correct, but your original remark about "do not fit" could be misunderstood as claiming that the Normal distribution evaluated at +2 is not 100 - 2.5%. Correct or not, that's really just a distraction.  The basic problem is that an assertion about individual people in a population is being (invalidly) justified by the CLT, as pointed out by the OP.

Comment: I can just delete it, if you prefer?

Comment: @Forgottenscience to make it clear, this question was asked as a way to think about CLT - so we need to figure out if the statement is true or not. Hence, my reasoning.

Comment: @Forgottenscience what do you mean when you say the standard deviation and probability do not fit?